# How to get values in a data range in R

Tags: r, indexing

I have a table that goes as follows:

`Zip Code  ApprovalRate ...`

`75229     0.32         ...`

I split my approval rate by quantiles, so discounting the zip codes with approval rate 0 or 100%, the breaks are `0.0303 0.3333 0.4394 0.5060 0.6190 0.9524` which I am naming `Very Low, Low, Med, High, Very High`

Now I would like to make a new vector of `lowZip` which are the zip codes for which the approval rate falls into the `Low` range of `0.0303 - 0.3333`

I have tried something like

`idxLow = which(0.0303 <= Approval & Approval <= 0.333)`

and then

`zipLow = mydata[idxLow, 1]`

But I have to think there is a better way.

Comment: `idxLow = which(0.0303 <= Approval & Approval <= 0.333)` shouldn't it be `idxLow = which(0.0303 >= Approval & Approval <= 0.333)`

Comment: No because I want the rate in the range [0.0303, 0.3333]

Comment: @Zvpunry Your method seems fine, not sure how to improve, unless you already created a new column with the `Very Low`, `Low`, etcetera values. Then you could just select based on that, e.g., `zipLow <- `mydata[mydata$Quantile == "Low",1]`.

Comment: Your range would give me Approval values below 0.0303 AND below 0.333...which doesn't really make sense right?

Comment: @RichardScriven That won't work as it's an integer range specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
 mydata[0.0303 <= Approval & Approval <= 0.333, 1]
```

Should work.